# How to write in the background view (Instructions mainly) of UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to achieve something like this

[image]

mainly for Instruction purpose, is there a UITableView method I am unaware of, or there is some sort of trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make same kind of view (as per above shown image),put a label in the footer of the section,make the background of the label transparent and set its frame according to your choice and add the text which you want to put over there. let me give you a code snippet which might help you.

```
UILabel *tableFooter = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect];
tableFooter.textColor = // add color of your choice
tableFooter.backgroundColor = // add color of your choice
tableFooter.opaque = YES;
tableFooter.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
tableFooter.text = @" add text of your choice";
self.theTable.tableFooterView = tableFooter;
[tableFooter release];
```

Put the above code in this method :

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is written in Header and Footer of UItableView. So customize headerView and footerView of sections in table.**

Use these methods :

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this delegate method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Answer (score 0):

You following methods its works for me in my app :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /* ios 7 Change */
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
         self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
         self.tableview.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
         [self.tableview setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
   }
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *header;

    float start = 10.0, startLabel = 10.0;

    if ([UICommonUtils isiPad]) 
    {
        startLabel = 50.0;
    } else {
        startLabel = 10.0;
    }

    CGRect rectFrame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;


        UIView* customView = [[[UIView alloc] 
                           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(start, 0.0, rectFrame.size.width - 20.0, 80.0)]
                          autorelease];
    /*
     customView.backgroundColor = 
     [UIColor colorWithRed:.6 green:.6 blue:1 alpha:.9];
     */
        UILabel * headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        //UILabel * headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault] autorelease];
        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headerLabel.opaque = NO;
        //headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.298039 green:0.337255 blue:0.423529 alpha:1];
        headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
        //headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(startLabel, 0, rectFrame.size.width - 60.0, 20.0);
        headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(startLabel, 10, rectFrame.size.width - 35.0, 20.0);
        headerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        headerLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        headerLabel.text = header;
        headerLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignCenters;

        UILabel * footerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
        //UILabel *footerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault] autorelease];
        footerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        footerLabel.opaque = NO;
        //footerLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
        footerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.298039 green:0.337255 blue:0.423529 alpha:1];
        footerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        footerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
        footerLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
        float height;
        if ([UICommonUtils isiPad])
            height = 40.0;
        else 
            height = 50.0;
        footerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(startLabel, 20, rectFrame.size.width - 60.0, height);
        footerLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        footerLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        footerLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentNone;
        footerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        footerLabel.text = detail;

        [customView addSubview:headerLabel];
        [customView addSubview:footerLabel];

        return customView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([UICommonUtils isiPad]) return 60.0;
        else return 70.0;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
return kProductHeader;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 /* ios 7 Change */
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
        if (tableView == self.tableview) {
            CGFloat cornerRadius = 5.f;
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
            CAShapeLayer *layer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
            CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
            CGRect bounds = CGRectInset(cell.bounds, 10, 0);
            BOOL addLine = NO;
            if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
                CGPathAddRoundedRect(pathRef, nil, bounds, cornerRadius, cornerRadius);
            } else if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds));
                addLine = YES;
            } else if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
                CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMinX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddArcToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMaxY(bounds), CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds), cornerRadius);
                CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, nil, CGRectGetMaxX(bounds), CGRectGetMinY(bounds));
            } else {
                CGPathAddRect(pathRef, nil, bounds);
                addLine = YES;
            }
            layer.path = pathRef;
            CFRelease(pathRef);
            layer.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.f alpha:0.8f].CGColor;

            if (addLine == YES) {
                CALayer *lineLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
                CGFloat lineHeight = (1.f / [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
                lineLayer.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(bounds)+10, bounds.size.height-lineHeight, bounds.size.width-10, lineHeight);
                lineLayer.backgroundColor = tableView.separatorColor.CGColor;
                [layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
            }
            UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
            [testView.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
            testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor;
            cell.backgroundView = testView;
        }
    }
}
```